# How to change the default copyright text in the ACM sigconf template?

Tags: acm, copyright

How to change this default copyright text with an alternative text?

[image: Default Text]

Comment: The `acmart` document class provides commands for generating different copyright text; have a look at the (very well-written) package documentation: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acmart/acmart.pdf

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information.